# xcodebuild -list can not find scheme which existed

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-scheme

I have xcode project, I want to build this project under command line, this project composed many sub-project, first I fetch these source files to local disk, I use xcodebuild -list to find scheme, I can not find anything, while after I manually open this project with xcode and then use xcodebuild -list to find scheme, some scheme can be seen.

I compare the project file of these two scenario, for the second project, there existed xcuserdata folder, so I can find the scheme, the problem I need use scheme to build this project.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that for `-scheme` builds to work correctly you need to have the `project.xcworkspace/` directory in place within the `.xcodeproj` directory. The `project.xcworkspace/` directory should have a `contents.xcworkspacedata` file within it.

In my case, the `project.xcworkspace/` directory wasn't it the git repository because it wasn't previously necessary so I had `*.xcworkspace` in my `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

check the file *.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/*.xcuserdatad/xcschemes exists,if not open *.xcodeproj and the file will be created by xcode,then get the current Schemes from xcodebuild -list